# What is a variable type bit(32)?

Tags: c++, binary

What is a variable of type bit(32) and when can I use it? I also can't seem to replicate this declaration in my own C++ code (in xcode). This is an example of it being used in mp4 file specifications, as part of variable declarations within a class:

```
bit(32)[6]  pre_defined = 0;
```

```
aligned(8) class MovieHeaderBox extends FullBox(‘mvhd’, version, 0) {
 if (version==1) {
  unsigned int(64) creation_time;
  unsigned int(64) modification_time;
  unsigned int(32) timescale;
  unsigned int(64) duration;
 } else { // version==0
  unsigned int(32) creation_time;
  unsigned int(32) modification_time;
  unsigned int(32) timescale;
  unsigned int(32) duration;
 }
 template int(32) rate = 0x00010000; // typically 1.0
 template int(16) volume = 0x0100; // typically, full volume
 const bit(16) reserved = 0;
 const unsigned int(32)[2] reserved = 0;
 template int(32)[9] matrix = { 0x00010000,0,0,0,0x00010000,0,0,0,0x40000000 };
 // Unity matrix
 bit(32)[6] pre_defined = 0;
 unsigned int(32) next_track_ID;
}
```

Comment: There is no such type in standard C++. And, without you providing the library you are using, that contains definition for such type - it's difficult to answer you.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show that it's from a formal ISO specification of media file formats, including mp4. See the second last line

Comment: @JohnPaoletto perhaps the standard document explains what it means

Comment: Where did you get the screenshot from?

Comment: Looks like this is the document: https://l.web.umkc.edu/lizhu/teaching/2016sp.video-communication/ref/mp4.pdf

Comment: I think this is just supposed to be highly specific pseudocode. It certainly isn't C++, not just because of those bit numbers. You also can't declare class fields in an `if` block like that.

Comment: @doctorlove, this is from ISO/IEC 14496-12, Information technology — Coding of audio-visual objects —Part 12:
ISO base media file format. It's the formal document that outlines the specifications for the ISO base media file format, which is the base for mp4's too

Comment: So should I just assume that its a piece of data that takes up 32bits? In my case, an array of 6 elements, all 32bits each?

Comment: That suggests `box` is another type defined elsewhere. Moral of story - if you copy and paste snippets of code you might need to hunt out other parts.

Comment: @doctorlove, already did, still nothing unfortunately.

Comment: It is self explanatory. This is not a reason why it is standard C++. The problem is that standard C/C++ allow several sizes for int. But for a standardized bitstream, it essential to have no ambiguity in data size.

Comment: The doc listed by @Blaze suggests, on page 11, a `Box` class is used, "The definitions of boxes are given in the syntax description language (SDL)" so, assume nothing and copy/paste more code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @doctorlove I'll find this SDL outlines and see where I go from there, thx for your help. Essentially I'm unpacking mp4 files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not C++, just pseudo-code. It just means that it's 32-bit bool. So the valid values are 0 or 1, not all 32 bits and the name was probably also used to distinguish it from `unsigned int`. In C++ you have to use `std::uint32_t` or you can use enum:

```
enum class 32bitBool : std::uint32_t{
   Yes = 1,
   No = 0
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. By any chance, do you also know what the keyword 'template' means before an int(32) in that screenshot?

Comment: @JohnPaoletto Nope. But the document posted in the comments by Blaze says "Fields shown as “template” in the box descriptions are optional in the specifications that use this
specification. If the field is used in another specification, that use must be conformant with its definition here,
and the specification must define whether the use is optional or mandatory."

Answer (score 4):

The shown snippet is not C++. The standard that you quote says:

> The definitions of boxes are given in the syntax description language (SDL) defined in MPEG‐4 (see
> reference in Clause 2).

The language appears to be specified in ISO/IEC 14496-1. It says

> 12. Syntactic Description Language <sup>Note slight variation in name, than  what was referred to in  14496-12</sup>
>
> 12.2.1 Constant-Length Direct Representation Bit Fields
>
> Constant-length direct representation bit fields are represented as:
>
> Rule E.1: Elementary Data Types
>
> ```
> [aligned] type[(length)] element_name [= value]; // C++-style comments allowed
> ```
>
> The type can be any of the following: ‘int’ for signed integer, ‘unsigned int’ for unsigned integer, ‘double’ for floatingpoint, and **‘bit’ for raw binary data**.

Comment: @JohnPaoletto I found the definition